# Headless single-source library for JVM and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, scala, kotlin, scala.js

I need to write a library that can be **compiled to Java-classes** (to be more specific: Android) **and JavaScript** or TypeScript (modern Browser and Node.js).

The lib will deal with lists of objects with a lot of numbers and has to calculate statistics and filter/manipulate the lists. No rocket-science, dependencies can be bridged for each environment. No problems with decimal arithmetics. (=> The libs could be developed in TypeScript and Java, but nobody wants to maintain 2 semantically equal sources.)

I've no fear to learn a new language, but integration should be smooth (i.e. create a .jar with standard Java interface and Java types and a .js file for JavaScript/TypeScript without hundreds of kilobytes of runtime).

Could I choose **Scala/Scala.js** for this?

Would it work with **Kotlin**?

Has anybody of you guys managed an equal task successfully? What are the caveats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the basics are very normal for Scala/Scala.js these days -- many libraries cross-compile with no changes. The Scala.js compiler is highly optimized, and only includes code that is actually invoked, so the output is reasonably lean. (Unless you need bulky external dependencies, which the SJS compiler can't do much about.)

Managing the dependency differences will be some extra effort, if you need to deal with them differently on the two sides. This isn't terribly unusual for Scala/Scala.js, but does require that the project be structured for that. The [documentation of CrossProject](https://www.scala-js.org/api/sbt-scalajs/0.6.15/#org.scalajs.sbtplugin.cross.CrossProject) gets into the details.

But overall -- yeah, that's all fairly common at this point...